# Convert string to time xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsdate

I have a json containing various times. Like below

{
"5:10"
"14:24"
}
I need to use this time to fire local notification everyday.

Can you please suggest me how to properly put this string in this line?

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit |   NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate: now];
[componentsForFireDate setHour: 20] ;
[componentsForFireDate setMinute:0] ;
[componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;

NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForFireDate];
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification ;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"New updates!"] ;
notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New updates added for that week!"] forKey:@"new"];
notification.repeatInterval= NSDayCalendarUnit ;
notification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

NSLog(@"notification: %@",notification);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;
```

In this code I am manually adding the time to 8 pm.  I need to put that time from json into the code.

Comment: Well you need to create an NSDate from the stuff you receive in JSON though I think it is weird that your JSON has no indication about timezone. Why is that?

Comment: Also, What's 5:10? Is it the day and month? What is the format, DD:MM? Or MM:DD? Alot of info is missing there. People won't magically guess it so you have to add required info to your post. Moreover, is there a comma missing in your JSON? It should be like {"5:10", "14:40"}

Comment: yes it has a comma missing because i didnt post the original json. The json consist of a 24-hour format time. 
{
"05:10",
"14:24"
}
05:10 means 5 am

Comment: I want to fire a local notification everyday at a specific time. I know how to add the time manually as i mentioned in the code but i need to add the time that i obtain from my json as mentioned above.

Comment: Okay and what is 14:24 then?

Comment: it is also a time. These are the list of times i need to execute the the notification.